# Active class on node with NAVEE

Tags: navigation, menu

I have a simple nav tag

```
{% set navConfig = {
    'startwithActive' : true,
    'maxDepth' : 2,
    'activeClassOnAncestors' : true,
    'ancestorActiveClass' : 'active',
} %}
    {% nav node in navigation %}

      <li{% if node.class %} class="{{ node.class }}"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ node.link }}">{{ node.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
             <ul class="dropdown">{% children %}</ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

This works fine all but with the News section entries. my-site/news adds the active class to the link, but my-site/news/new-entry doesn't add the class to the ancestor.

I have tried most configurations with the available parameters and variables, but I cannot work it out.

Any help would be brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to look at is the Regular Expression option under the advanced tab for your my-site/news node. You could add something like:

```
 /^my-site\/news/i
```

This way all of the child pages in that section will mark the News page as active.

MW

Comment: Thanks Michael, I would have never come up with that.... Could you elaborate what the `activeClassOnAncestors : true`, does differently?